# Can CFFI use the same DLL with both Python 3.4 and 3.5?

Tags: python, windows, dll, python-cffi

This page documents the different versions of the Microsoft Visual C++ compiler needed for each Python version: https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers

I would like to use MinGW instead of Microsoft to compile a C library for 64-bit Windows 8.1, but I have read that MinGW-w64/mingwpy does not support Python 3.5: [Make cffi use MinGW under Python 3.5 on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39273989/make-cffi-use-mingw-under-python-3-5-on-windows)

I also see http://mxe.cc/ for cross-compiling to Windows, but it too uses the MinGW-w64 toolchain.

If I use CFFI's ABI in-line mode for the Python interface, can I compile a DLL for the C library once (with compatibility to Microsoft Visual C++ 10.0) and use it with both Python 3.4 and 3.5?  If so, is compatibility with Python 3.5 achieved because of static linking to the DLL?  I don't understand the subtleties of dynamic vs. static linking.

Comment: AFAIK in CFFI's ABI mode you're not building an extension module that links with the Python DLL. It's using `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress` to dynamically load and call functions in your DLL -- much like ctypes, but with a cleaner API that can do a lot of the tedious work for you by automatically parsing C header files.

Comment: If you're building with MinGW, the DLL itself will be linked to msvcrt.dll instead of the C runtime that Python uses, so the library API should avoid file descriptor and `FILE` pointer arguments (each CRT has its own low and standard I/O implementation that wraps Windows `File` handles) and encapsulate its memory management (each CRT may have its own heap, though I think the Universal CRT uses the default process heap) or require the client to allocate all memory. Other thread-local state such as `errno` and the locale is also unique to each CRT.

Answer (score 0):

If you use CFFI's ABI in-line mode, you don't need to compile anything.  You just need to install CFFI, which comes precompiled for Windows.

If you use the recommmended CFFI's API mode, you need a compiler.  The complete requirements on Windows are too complicated for me to make sense, but note that the CFFI-generated extension module should be compiled in what CPython calls the "stable ABI" mode.  That is, a single compiled `.pyd` is enough for all versions of CPython 3.x.  I would guess that you can pick whichever version of CPython you have the proper compiler toolchain for, and use it to compile the `.pyd`.

Comment: When you say I don't need to compile anything with the ABI in-line mode, does that mean CFFI will read my source code?  Does Python's interpreter replace a compiler?

Comment: In ABI mode, you only put C function declarations inside ``ffi.cdef()``, and that is parsed by CFFI without using a compiler.  There is no actual C source code in that mode.